# Store metadata for files in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Image files stored in Google Drive have an [imageMediaMetadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#imageMediaMetadata) property, containing metadata about the file.

Will it be possible to add structured metadata to other file types, perhaps using the properties from [schema.org](http://schema.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(the other answers are good, but just to add)

Sorry, this is not currently available. However, this is a high-priority feature, with a number of tricky technical difficulties that Google is working on. It was announced at Google IO 2012 as "coming soon", so stay tuned.

Comment: It would be really handy to understand the direction that Google is taking on this. My bet would be that structuring the metadata as  JSON would provide a forward path. Putting stringified JSON in the description might then be a temporary expedient. indexableText is described as write only which would reduce its utility.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, no, it is not possible yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [indexableText](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) attribute for this, you would need to provide the structure yourself.